# What does "that" in "put that back" refer to?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In *Mortal Kombat* (2021), at Raiden's temple, Liu Kang describes the opponent's strength:

> Liu Kang: The Dragon has swallowed many before us.

Liu Kang comes to Kano:

> Liu Kang: Now put **that** back.
>
> Kano: Put what back?

Then Sonya follows bell chimes only to find Jax being treated on a bed.

What does "that" in "put that back" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kano stole '*the Amulet of Shinnok*' a few seconds earlier in the scene. That is the 'that' that is being referred to when Liu Kang says 'that'.